# WPF WindowChrome with background - system buttons are hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I am creating custom WPF Window using `WindowChrome`. I have my own style defined but title bar presents problem. If I set `Background` of my main `Grid` in template to Transparent then the whole window uses system accent colors and `Maximize/Minimize/Close` buttons are visible.

When I set any other background `Maximize/Minimize/Close` buttons get covered. I thought I just make my own, but those buttons are still clickable.

Is there any way to either show them or disable completely?

I can set `CaptionHeight` to 0 and create mi own title bar, but I don't want to reimplement drag and other default features.

My Style is below:

```
<Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="-1" 
                            ResizeBorderThickness="4"
                            CaptionHeight="36"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ConfigurationWindow}" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                       Height="35" ></Rectangle>
                            <!-- This is the ContentPresenter that displays the window content. -->
                            <Border Margin="0,40,0,5" >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <!--This is the transparent white rectangle that goes behind the window content.-->
                            <Border Margin="1,40,1,5" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
                  Grid.ZIndex="-1">
                                <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0.5" />
                            </Border>

                            <!-- Window Title -->
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" 
                       Padding="0,3,0,8" 
                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
```

Comment: Why don't you set GlassFrameThickness="0"? It's one of common settings to hide default buttons.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Dunno how I managed to miss it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @emoacht commented, seeing `GlassFrameThickness` to zero removes the invisible close/max/min buttons. You can still drag the window by the title area.

Setting `GlassFrameThickness` is intended to make the entire window glassy in that Aero way from Windows 7.

Also, you don't need to use the [`Microsoft.Windows.Shell` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Shell) any more. The class you're after is in the framework now, as `System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome` (in `PresentationFramework.dll`).